# ¿Por qué no me muestra el texto en pantalla?

Tags: c

Quiero guardar un texto almacenado de teclado pero no sé qué ocurre que la salida no es la esperada. Se trata de un ejercicio de una lista enlazada en la que, con un struct, tengo que almacenar código, texto (máx. 33 caracteres) y componente siguiente. El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

**Componentes.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "componentes.h"

Lista Lista_Crear(){
    Lista lista = NULL;
    return lista;
}

int Lista_Vacia (Lista lista){
    return lista->sig == NULL;
}

void Adquirir_Componente(long *codigo,char *texto){
    texto = (char*)malloc(MAX_CADENA+1);
    printf("Introduzca el código: \n");
    scanf("%ld", codigo);
    //printf("%ld", codigo);
    printf("\nIntroduzca el texto: ");
    scanf("%s", texto);
    //printf("%s\n", texto);
}
```

**Componentes.h**

```
#define COMPONENTES_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CADENA 33

/*
-----------DEFINICION DE ALIAS DE TIPOS-----------------
*/

/*
Esta sera la estructura principal de los nodos de nuestra lista
*/

typedef struct elemLista {
    long codigoComponente;
    char textoFabricante[MAX_CADENA];
    struct elemLista * sig;
} Componente;

/*
Definimos el tipo lista como un puntero al tipo Componente que constituye el tipo de los nodos de nuestra lista
*/
typedef Componente * Lista;

*(Aparte del resto del código que en este caso es irrelevante)*
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "componentes.h"

/*
-----------DEFINICION DE LA RUTINA main-----------------
*/

int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    int opcion;
    int salir = 0;
    long codigo;
    char texto[33];

    /*
    -----------------VARIABLES GLOBALES---------------------
    */
    Lista listaComponentes;

    listaComponentes = Lista_Crear();

    /*
    Para realizar el menu de seleccion, utilizamos un bucle while que solo terminara cuando
    la variable "salir" sea verdadera (contenga un 1), cosa que sucedera cuando se introduzca
    por teclado un valor distinto de 1,2,3,4 o 5.
    */
    while (!salir) {
        printf("*************************************************************************\n");
        printf("*   SELECCIONE LA OPERACION QUE DESEE REALIZAR Y PULSE INTRO            *\n");
        printf("*************************************************************************\n");
        printf("*   '1' Para anadir un nuevo componente al final de la lista            *\n");
        printf("*   '2' Para borrar el ultimo componente de la lista                    *\n");
        printf("*   '3' Para salvar la lista en fichero                                 *\n");
        printf("*   '4' Para vaciar por completo la lista                               *\n");
        printf("*   '5' Para imprimir la lista                                          *\n");
        printf("*   '6' Para salir del programa                                        *\n");
        printf("*************************************************************************\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        switch (opcion) {
        case 1: Adquirir_Componente(&codigo,texto);
                printf("%ld, %s", codigo, texto);
                Lista_Agregar(&listaComponentes,codigo,texto);
                Lista_Imprimir(listaComponentes);
                break;
*(Aparte del resto del código que en este caso es irrelevante)*
```

Al llamar desde **main** a *Adquirir_Componente* pongo de código *1* y de texto *hola*, pero al pasar a la instrucción siguiente, la de printf, la salida por pantalla que obtengo es *1, ?·@-*.

Answer (score 1):

> > Al llamar desde main a Adquirir_Componente pongo de código 1 y de texto hola, pero al pasar a la instrucción siguiente, la de printf, la salida por pantalla que obtengo es 1, ?·@-.

Claro, es porque estás sobrescribiendo el contenido del parámetro `texto`.

Cuando invocas a esta función:

```c
Adquirir_Componente(&codigo,texto);
```

Le pasas al segundo parámetro la dirección base del arreglo y se supone que la función debe modificar dicho contenido, sin embargo, cuando se ejecute esta instrucción:

```c
texto = (char*)malloc(MAX_CADENA+1);
```

Estarías sobrescribiendo la dirección de memoria que tenía guardado el puntero `texto`. Por lo tanto, reservar memoria con `malloc` es inútil, debido a que, cuando la función `Adquirir_Componente` termine su ejecución, toda la memoria que consumía dicha rutina es liberada y por ende, se pierde el texto que haya introducido el usuario (ya que no tienes un puntero para poder acceder a dicho bloque que se haya reservado con `malloc`) y de paso ocurre una fuga de memoria.

**Solución:** Elimina ese `malloc`.

El código queda así:

```c
void Adquirir_Componente(long *codigo, char *texto)
{
    printf("Introduzca el código: \n");
    scanf("%ld", codigo);
    printf("\nIntroduzca el texto: ");
    scanf("%s", texto);
}
```

**Observación:**

Posible [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) en esta línea:

```c
scanf("%s", texto);
```

Si el usuario ingresa más de 33 caracteres, desbordas el búfer y esto ocasiona que se sobrescriba una zona de memoria.

**Solución rápida:** Escribe el tamaño del búfer en el especificador de formato:

```c
scanf("%33s", texto);
```